# Can't run WPS Office in Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, wps-office

I could install with an error message "unknown media /ALL". It could not run WPS Office.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

WPS Office is an office productivity suite, including Writer, Presentation and Spreadsheets. WPS Office is a native snap package in Kubuntu and other Ubuntu flavors. To install it in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install wps-office  
sudo snap connect wps-office:removable-media
```

In order to install  WPS Office Suite with support for many languages type:

```
sudo snap install wps-office-multilang
```

To list the supported languages of wps-office-multilang run `snap info wps-office-multilang`.

The wps-office snap packages will be updated automatically when updates are available.

Comment: this didn't work for me in ubuntu 18.04.