# WPS Office error: cannot satisfy dependencies, kubuntu 18.04

Tags: kubuntu, architecture, wps-office

I'm trying to install WPS office in kubuntu . i've got this error :   cannot satisfy dependencies.

I try to install libpng12-0 but the error is still occurred. anyone help me to fix this issue

[image]

[image]

Comment: In a terminal, enter `sudo apt install wps-office` and tell us which dependencies are a problem.

Comment: See the added picture above

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package wps-office:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'wps-office:i386' has no installation candidate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install wps office via terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/783927/how-to-install-wps-office-via-terminal) and [Can't run WPS Office in Kubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091149/)

Comment: The native WPS snap package in 18.04 also is updated automatically like an installation from a .deb file.

Comment: I got this ```E: The package wps-office:i386 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.``` when i try to run ```sudo apt autoremove wps-office```

Comment: I got the same error message

Comment: Your system is a 64-bit architecture. Did you - at one point - install a 32-bit version (i386)?

Comment: my system is 64bit. i don't understand you

Comment: what should i do

Comment: this is the name of the package i've installed : ```wps-office_10.1.0.6757_i386```

Comment: You should have installed `wps-office_10.1.0.6757_amd64`. Please uninstall the `i386` version and try again.